# Files go missing after copying - Android

Tags: android, file, android-sdcard, android-file

I am moving files(around 100-2000 files each of size 100-200KB) via thread from one folder to another. All goes well but on some Samsung & LG devices with **sdcard**, suddenly after copying, all or some of them go missing.

This does not happen every time, but approximately around once in every 20 times.

I have tried 3 techniques so far:

```
public void copyMethodA(File src, File dst){
    if(!dst.exists()){
        src.renameTo(dst);
    }
}
```

copyMethodA(); resulted in loss of file in most of the times.

```
public void copyMethodB(File sourceFile, File destFile) throws IOException {

    if (!destFile.exists()) {
        destFile.createNewFile();
    }

    try {
        FileChannel source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
        FileChannel destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();
        destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
    } finally {
        source.close();
        destination.close();
    }
}
```

copyMethodB(); resulted in loss of file comparatively less number of times than A.

```
public void copyMethodC(File src, File dst) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst);

    byte[] buf = new byte[10240];
    int len;
    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```

copyMethodC(); very rarely resulted in loss of files. **Hence currently using this one**.

All 3 methods worked fine without a single loss of file on Xperia C & Nexus 5(both using internal storage)
***But loss of files was observed on LG Optimus One(using sdcard) and some Samsung devices(using internal or sdcard)***

Info about devices on which I have tested:

- Nexus 5 - Android 4.4.2
- Xperia C - Android 4.2.2
- LG Optimus One - Android 2.3.3
- Samsung devices - Android 4.0 and above

(I guess this problem isn't related to version of Android used)

I am avoiding to use huge 3rd party File IO API's as my Android app's size is just 300KB. Using API like Apache commons.io will bloat it to around 2.5MB

Is there any other safe, secure & better way to copy files ?

Thanks.

Comment: renameTo() function should actually work. It is the fastest and simplest one.

Comment: Yes, that was my first priority but resulted in most frequent loss of file.

Comment: How do you determine whether a file "goes missing"?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should something like this :

- you should check the return value of `renameTo` as, as the [javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29) states it, there are many reasons for it to fail.
- If the `renameTo` call failed, use the third way, with try / catch  blocks to catch IOException when reading / writing the streams and make sure you only delete the source file if the copy was successful. You can then check the exception to understand why the copy failed and possibly retry it later.

I'm doing this (with a 1024 bytes buffer, like in @beni answer) to copy a few hundred files and I've never seen any loss.

Comment: Currently I am using same method as you and @beni have advised via byte buffer.
Moreover, I am verifying if file has been successfully copied like this:
if (src.length() == dst.length()) {
    src.delete();
}

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Scards are a whole different mount point, so you cannot rename files between SD and internal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this function and always works. I test this code on Nexus 5. in.read(buf) method returns -1 when is in the end of the file in other case return the number of the bytes readed. So, try this.

```
public static void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Will check this out and let you know.